# django only allow to add new items to m2m field when update

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a m2m field as -

```
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size,blank=True,related_name='doto_sizes', default=5)
```

I am using generic update view for updating model, but what I want is, while updating `sizes` user is only able to add new sizes. He/she is not allowed to remove initial sizes.

To make it possible, I can define custom validations in `clean` method, but I am here because it is possible that django have built in method for that.

I even don't want that user can remove initial `sizes` in update form, How can I make it possible ?

Comment: can you add to question your models.py?

Comment: I can but could you tell me how this can help you ? Question is clear itself.

Comment: Ok, you can use `through` model which always created when you specified m2m relationship to update your instances. This model contains two FK. In your case one for `Size` model, and another for model where you create m2m relation. You can get this `YourModelSizeLink = YourModel.sizes.through` and using this model you can update, delete or whatever instances. But better to create link model clearly and pass it ti `through` attribute `sizes = models.ManyToManyField(..., through='YourLinkModel',..)`

Comment: read this [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) it can help you.